# I want to set 1 hour interval in UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I am using `UIDatepicker` and I want to show I hour interval like 1: 00, 2: 00, 3:00 and so on.
Minute interval is maximum of 30 minutes only.

```
self.view_pickerview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.view_pickerview];
self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
self.datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.frame.size.width, 180.0f); // set frame as your need
self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];
[self.datePicker setLocale:locale];
```

Comment: Show us your code

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not available with UIDatePicker. You can use [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview)

By setting data source and delegate to pickerView and

1. Set `numberOfComponents(in:)` to 2,
2. `pickerView(_:numberOfRowsInComponent:)`
   to 24 hours and 30 for minutes in respective components.
3. You can pass your required titles `pickerView(_:titleForRow:forComponent:)`

By this way, you can achieve the same results.